# How to get real time current battery level in Android API level 23 and above

Tags: android

i want to get the current battery level of the device in my app which has API level 23 an above.The change in battery level should produce toasts to the app as soon as the battery level is updated.

Comment: What do you have currently that isn't working on those API levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to major changes in battery level by registering to a *broadcast* made by the system as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This goes inside your *manifest file*. Declaring a receiver.

Alternatively you can also check current battery level as given in detail on [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel).

It might be the case that you want to check battery level on a regular basis that is after regular time intervals. In such a case you can schedule a piece of code that would run repeatedly and do the job that you intend to do.

If you want to read about how to Schedule some task, [this link if useful](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html).